# How to remove session login for specific user

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session, authentication

I am creating a login session for each user. This is my session function:

```
public function check_login()
{
    $uname  = $this->input->post('username');
    $passwd = $this->input->post('password');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','user_name','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','password','required');

    if( $this->form_validation->run() == false )
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->model('model_login');
        $result = $this->model_login->query_login();

        if(!$result)
        { $this->load->view('login'); }
        else
        {
            //Log History
            $id_user                = $this->session->userdata('id_user');
            $data_log['id_user']    = $this->session->userdata('id_user');
            $data_log['log_time']   = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $data_log['status']     = 1;

            $this->model_login->insert_log($data_log);

            $data = array( 'log_status' => 1 );
            $this->model_login->update_log($data,$id_user);

            echo "<script>alert('Login Sukses')</script>";
            redirect(base_url() . 'con_vendor/index');
        }
    }
}
```

When an user Login or Logout, their history is recorded to database (see log history comment) and their login status changed to 1 (this mean they're online).

But, when an user Logout, it seems the session data for all user is removed, not just the user that logout. In the user_log db only the first user logout ID is recorded. The next user ID is not recorded though the logout time s recorded.

For example:

User A login, then User B login. All login data is recorded to the user_log table. Then User B logout and then user A logout. Only sesssion data for user B is recorded, User A sesion data is lost.

This is my logout function:

```
public function logout()
{
    $id_user                = $this->session->userdata('id_user');
    $data_log['id_user']    = $this->session->userdata('id_user');
    $data_log['log_time']   = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $data_log['status']     = 2;

    $this->model_login->insert_log($data_log);

    $data = array( 'log_status' => 0 );
    $this->model_login->update_log($data,$id_user);

    $arr_sess = array(  'id_user' => $this->session->userdata('id_user'),
                        'username' => $this->session->userdata('username'),
                        'level' => $this->session->userdata('level'),
                        'nip' => $this->session->userdata('nip'),
                        'bagian' => $this->session->userdata('bagian')
                     );

    $this->session->unset_userdata($arr_sess);      

    redirect('con_login/index');
}
```

The user_log table after user A and B login/logout

```
No     user_id    log_time   status
1      USER_B       10:25         1     //1 is login and 2 is logout
2      USER_A       11:03         1
3      USER_B       11:45         2
4      (no data)    11:55         2
```

Comment: How are you performing the logins? On the same Browser? The danger is you could be logging in under the same session so when you logout one, you are killing the one and only session. You could prove this by displaying the session_id for each login... A better way is you use two browsers which should give you two sessions. But again check it with the session_ids.

Comment: yes I tested it on the same browser on the same PC

Comment: Totally unaccepted testing method!!! Use different machine or atleast different browser...

Comment: Well, I just test it on a different browser. and it works. Silly me.

Comment: btw, do you guys know why this line is not working `echo "<script>alert('Login Sukses')</script>";`

Answer (score 1):

you need to save the sessions into the database and check client session (code to the header.php) if session from database still available the user can be on but if the session has been deleted redirect the user to the logout page.
Notice : you can remove the session from the admin panel. ( just a simple mysql code)